# Using True/False as keys - how/why does this work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I am comfortable using this simple syntax for initializing a `dictionary`

```
d = {'a':'Apple','b':'Bat'};
```

Today, while reading a page, I encountered this weird piece of code

```
{True:0, False:1}[True];
```

I was wondering why/how that could work? `True` and `False` are reserved keywords, 
and so, that crazy syntax should be meaningless (for the compiler), but it is 
not.

```
>>> d = {True:0, False:1};
>>> d
{False: 1, True: 0}
```

And this gets crazier

```
>>> d = dict(True = 0, False = 1);
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
>>> d = dict(_True = 0, _False = 1);
>>> d
{'_False': 1, '_True': 0}
```

In `dict()` constructor, `True` keyword is not allowed! But...

---

**Update**

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('print');
False
>>> keyword.iskeyword('else');
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword('True');
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword('False');
True
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While they are keywords (in Python 3), `True` and `False` are still names of objects (they are, respectively `bool(1)` and `bool(0)`).

So you can use them anywhere a value makes sense. Since they're hashable, that includes using them as dictionary keys. You can do:

```
d = {}
d[True] = "True"
d[False] = "False"
```

You can get the same dictionary directly with curly brackets (`d = {True: "True", False: "False"}`), but not using the `dict` constructor with keyword arguments. The keyword version of the constructor only builds dicts with keys that are strings, and those strings must be legal Python identifiers. `True` and `False` are not strings, nor (since they're keywords) can they be used as identifiers.

You can of course use the sequence of key/value tuples constructor, if there's some reason you need to be calling `dict` rather than using brackets:

```
d = dict([(True, "True"), (False, "False")])
```

I would note that the code fragment you show is a bit silly. The `bool` type in Python is a subclass of `int`, so you can do mathematical operations on `True` or `False` if you want. The dictionary indexing code is equivalent to `1-True`, which will be `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 4):

Why should it be meaningless? `True` and `False` are values, not keywords. That's why you can compare other values with them.

You can't use integers in the dict constructor, either. That's a limitation of keyword arguments, not of dictionaries.

Comment: They did become keywords in Python 3, but that only prevents redefining them in broken ways like `True = False`. Your question is generally correct though, it's their value that's the important bit.

Comment: >>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword('print');
False
>>> keyword.iskeyword('else');
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword('True');
True
>>> keyword.iskeyword('False');
True

Comment: @GLES fine, but the main point - and the answer to your question - is that they are also (and primarily) values.

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `False` aren't keywords -- they're actual objects. You can verify this in the Python interpreter (using 2.7 here, but the same holds in 3.x):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 29 2014, 21:22:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>> True.__class__.__name__
'bool'
>>> type(False)
<type 'bool'>
>>> False.__class__.__name__
'bool'
>>> hash(True)
1
>>> hash(False)
0
>>> True.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of bool object at 0x100134da0>
>>> False.__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of bool object at 0x100134db8>
```

So they can be used as keys in a dict or similar structure.

In fact, prior to Python 3, you *could* use `True` and `False` as parameter names to `dict()`:

```
>>> d = dict(True="true", False="false")
>>> d
{'False': 'false', 'True': 'true'}
```

However, to avoid confusion, the Python 3 interpreter prevents you from doing that, as it essentially treats them like keywords now -- but really, they're still objects. (I guess you could say they're both, sort of.)

Comment: The question is tagged Python 3.x, so saying that `True` and `False` are not keywords in Python 2 is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @Blckknght: I'm illustrating the progression of the language and showing how things changed slightly between 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time :)